# Is "CLR Integration" enabled at a database level or the server/instance level?

Tags: sql-server, database, .net-assembly, sqlclr

I am trying to understand whether enabling CLR enables it at a database-level or  server-level / instance-level. The Online books are not clear at all, what happens if I enable CLR using this command, would it be enabled across all of the servers??

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Comment: `sp_configure` is for instance-level configuration, hence it is instance-level. And why are you wanting database-level configuration?

Comment: Thanks LOL, I missed this one. Maybe you can answer my newest questions too perhaps??? lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CLR Integration is enabled at the server level (by the `sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1` code you posted).

Assemblies are loaded at the database level. CLR Stored Procedures and Functions are created from methods in those loaded assemblies at a database level.

Comment: what do you mean by "by the code you posted". Is there way to just enable CLR for just a single database? or isolate it somehow?

Comment: the code you posted is clearly visible, and No,  there isn't a way to just enable CLR for just a single database. But if you don't create any CLR procs in the database in question, the point is moot.