# How to enable CLR integration for just a specific database in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

[CLR integration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is disabled by default.  My understanding of the [instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131048%28SQL.100%29.aspx) to enable it implies that it is enabled or disabled for the entire server.  Is it possible to enable it on a per-database basis?  If so, how?

Comment: No, this is an instance level option.

There is no option to enable it for specific databases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is “CLR Integration” enabled at a database level or the server/instance level?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871314/is-clr-integration-enabled-at-a-database-level-or-the-server-instance-level).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling "CLR Integration" is a Server/Instance-level only option; it cannot be handled separately per Database.

However, while I am not sure why it would matter to handle this on a per-Database basis, you could always `DENY CREATE ASSEMBLY` in Databases where you do not want custom SQLCLR code being used.

**UPDATE**

I just tested `DENY CREATE ASSEMBLY TO [Public];` and this does not work for Logins that are a member of the `sysadmin` fixed server role. So another way to *effectively* deny permission to an action is to trap the action via a [DDL Trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx) and issue a `ROLLBACK` which will cancel the action.

The following is a DDL Trigger that works in whatever Database it is created in and traps both `CREATE ASSEMBLY` and `ALTER ASSEMBLY` statements, but still allows `DROP ASSEMBLY` (using `DDL_ASSEMBLY_EVENTS` as the Event Group would disallow all three actions):

```sql
USE [db_name];
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [PreventCreateAssembly]
ON DATABASE
AFTER ALTER_ASSEMBLY, CREATE_ASSEMBLY -- DDL_ASSEMBLY_EVENTS
AS

RAISERROR(N'Cannot CREATE or ALTER Assemblies!', 16, 1);
ROLLBACK;
GO
```

With this DDL Trigger in place, when I tried to create the Assembly, I now receive the following error, even though my Login is a `sysadmin`:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PreventCreateAssembly, Line 59
>   Cannot CREATE or ALTER Assemblies!
>   Msg 3609, Level 16, State 2, Line 54
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Comment: Of course this won't prevent a login in the sysadmin role from disabling the trigger, but if that's the problem you have then your problem is not really a technical one anymore.

Comment: @BaconBits True and True. Though, there is no way really to prevent a `sysadmin` from doing anything: turning on/off "CLR Integration" or re-granting the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` had that worked. I think the benefit here is that at least something like an automated rollout script (that runs as `sysadmin`) would be prevented, where it would be allowed if only DENYing CREATE ASSEMBLY to Public.